# Jpg Image width/height vs compression ratio trade-off

Tags: image, delphi, graphics, resize

I'm re-sizing a photo from camera (usually 1000+ pixels wide at least).  Target thumbnail is say about 300 width by 225 height in display.

How much should I shrink the width and height to, before I use the jpg compression to bring down the size further?

Should I bring the width and height to 300 x 225, or larger?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. If your target size is 300 by 225 pixels you should shrink your picture to that size first and then encode it to JPEG. Encoding does not change the picture's dimensions, only the size in bytes.

Comment: And by the way: If I remember correctly JPEG encoding works on 8x8 squares, so you should use a multiple of 8 for width and height if possible.

Comment: somehow I had the impression that shrinking it to say slightly bigger than 300x225 will make it display sharper.. .as TImage will auto display a larger image in a 300x225 placeholder... ?   and also if the user resize it *slightly* larger, then at least the larger image will help.